# A problem regarding numbers

Tags: nouns, legalese, countability

Meaning of the word **ground** is reason.

But in the following sentence

> Despite governments bringing in legislation towards this end, they
>   have been struck down on the **grounds** that the additional quota
>   would take the quantum of reservation above the 50% limit set by the
>   Supreme Court in the Indra Sawhney judgment.

Ground is only one, but we are using word **grounds**. According to me it must be formed this way

> They have been struck down on the **ground** that...........

Comment: https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/with-reservations/article26324114.ece

Answer (score 4):

In legal usage, it is common to use ***grounds*** in the plural regardless of the number of discernable grounds. Or it might be better understood as being a mass noun.

Most mass nouns look like singulars, and are grammatically singular. Where a noun can be used as a countable noun and as a mass noun, it's usually in the singular for the mass noun - a recent answer I posted on this site was about *technology* as a mass noun. But some mass nouns are plural - either always a mass noun and grammatically plural, or a noun that can be mass or countable, and the mass version is the plural.

An example of a mass noun that is always plural is *[lees](https://www.winespectator.com/glossary/index/word/lees)*. Lees are the sediment of dead yeast and other material left when wine has fermented. There is no singular *lee* that corresponds, and the word is grammatically plural.

I would say that ***grounds***, in the legal sense, is a plural mass noun that happens to also be the plural of the countable noun *ground*. Thus, one says that the grounds of a case *are* such-and-such, even when there is only one reason or basis.